# How to change the Label Series to angle to 90°(vertical) of Chart c#

Tags: c#

I developed a chart C# with dynamic data with SQL Server 2008 Connection. The Label Series is located in horizontal position, but I need to change to a vertical position (90°) This code built a Web Form and add labels.

```
<asp:Chart ID="graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo" runat="server" Height="580px" Width="934px">
    <Series>
        <asp:Series CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder" Legend="Legend1" Name="Series1" LabelAngle="90">
        </asp:Series>
        <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder" Legend="Legend1" Name="Series2">
        </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisY IsLabelAutoFit="False" TextOrientation ="Auto"
                    TitleFont="Verdana, 10pt" Interval="Auto">
                    <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
            </AxisY>

            <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="10" 
                    LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" LabelAutoFitStyle="None" Interval="1">
                    <LabelStyle Angle ="90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif" IsEndLabelVisible ="false" />                            
            </AxisX>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
    <Legends>
        <asp:Legend Name="Legend1">
        </asp:Legend>
    </Legends>
</asp:Chart>
```

This code C# add Legends and tooltips to Chart. I checked into chart's properties but I don't find it! Can you Help Me Please! The picture is my Chart Now, And shows you that I want to organize

```
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Titles.Add("Comparativa Vehiculos Ralenti Promedio \\n" + strmes + " VS " + strmes_comparativo).Font = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Series["Series1"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Series["Series2"].ToolTip = "(#VALX, #VALY)";

graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Series["Series1"].LegendText = strmes;
graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Series["Series2"].LegendText = strmes_comparativo;

graf_hr_ralenti_vehiculo_mensual_comparativo.Legends["Legend1"].Title = "Segmentación";
```

Thanks[image]

Comment: You may need to disable SmartLabelStyle.

Comment: Thanks, but SmartLabelStyle don't control the label position!

Comment: But while it is on the labels will not be rotated as the Labels will be smart enough to know no rotation is necessary.. The default is `true`. Feel free to test it or at least to [look it up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.smartlabelstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)..

Comment: your are allright!

Comment: `series.SmartLabelsStyle.Enabled = false;series.LabelAngle = -90;` Reference:[Rotate Chart Data Point Label](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/65d15171-a437-484a-8aee-3d50cb5a120f/rotate-chart-data-point-label?forum=MSWinWebChart)

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution, into properties select "Series"\SmartLabelStyle - False
Then Select Font\LabelAngle -90.
Thanks for your help!
[image]

[image]